# Triple hierarchical entity mapping with hibernate/spring data causes infinite recursive loop

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, stack-overflow

I'm challenging with a problem. So: I have five entities, wchich has a relational mapping to others. This is how this structure looks:

[Relation diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giSS3.png)

Book.java entity

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "book")
private Set<Review> reviews = new HashSet<>();
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "book")
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.DETACH,
        CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "author_last_name")
@JsonBackReference
private Author author;
```

Author.java entity:

```
    @JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH},
        mappedBy = "author")
private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
```

Review.java entity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
@JsonBackReference
private Book book;
```

Comment.java entity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
@JsonBackReference
private Book book;
```

In each entity i have getters/setter/hashCode etc. Methods to add review to book or book to author are also present.

```
    public void addBookToAuthor(Book book){
    books.add(book);
    book.setAuthor(this);
}
```

And the problem is that i can get all authors, get single author etc. but when im trying to set couple of books to an Author this way:

```
    public void shouldSaveAnAuthorAndSetBooks(){
        Author author = authorService.findAuthorByLastName("qwerty");
        HashSet<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
        books.add(bookService.findById(5));
        books.add(bookService.findById(8));
        books.add(bookService.findById(10));
        books.forEach(book -> author.addBookToAuthor(book));
        authorRepository.save(author);
}
```

It's leading me to infinite loop where hibernate are selecting all books/reviews/comments:

```
Hibernate: select reviews0_.book_id as book_id5_4_0_, reviews0_.review_id as review_i1_4_0_, reviews0_.review_id as review_i1_4_1_, reviews0_.book_id as book_id5_4_1_, reviews0_.review as review2_4_1_, reviews0_.review_downvotes as review_d3_4_1_, reviews0_.review_upvotes as review_u4_4_1_ from review reviews0_ where reviews0_.book_id=?
```

this line is printing 1000+ times. Then showing 1000+ warnings about Fail-safe cleanup, and finally throwing the StackOverFlowExc this way:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1220)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:952)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:419)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:191)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2223)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:565)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:430)
at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4146)
at java.util.Objects.hash(Objects.java:128)
at com.example.com.example.entity.Book.hashCode(Book.java:190)
at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4146)
at java.util.Objects.hash(Objects.java:128)
at com.example.com.example.entity.Review.hashCode(Review.java:93)
at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:327)
```

Of course this stacktrace is too, showed in loop. So my question is: what can i do? Do i have to change mappings? Or approach to saving?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem was trivial. There was a bug in overrided HashCode method on book & review entity. So the moral is: do not use HashSet or HashMap and let your IDE generate hashcode for you. Better write it yourself